# Break if check in thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, break

My program is coded in Java. I have an IF() check in run() method (in a Thread). In the IF check, if the condition is satisfied, it shows a Window dialog (using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog) with OK button. However, it shows infinitely. When I click OK it pops up again and again. How can I end the if check after the user click OK. Or when the condition is met, it only shows once ?

This is my method()

```
public void danhHoiWumpus()
{
    if ((GameScreen.bg[x[0] + 1][y[0]] == 2) || (GameScreen.bg[x[0] + 2][y[0]] == 2) || (GameScreen.bg[x[0] + 3][y[0]] == 2) || (GameScreen.bg[x[0]][y[0]+1] == 2) || (GameScreen.bg[x[0]][y[0]+2] == 2) || (GameScreen.bg[x[0]][y[0]+3] == 2))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Có mùi wumpus  ! \n Bạn được học bổng 40%");

    }
}
```

This is my run() method

```
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            hunter.update();
            hunter.danhHoiWumpus();

//            i++;
            repaint();
//            System.out.println("Gia tri cua y la " +i);
            try {
                thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea of this action is. When the RED square is going near the YELLOW square, it will pop up a dialog "I smell Wumpus". When the user click OK. They will choose to shot the wumpus (I will do this later).

And here is my full source code (for reference):

```
https://www.mediafire.com/?wkp6hyq32nq23mp
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're asking why the code you're not showing is not working right, and this sort of thing is very hard for us to debug. Please help us -- show your code.

Comment: thank you, I will add my code now

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing in an infinite while loop

```
while(true)

    // I am infinite

}
```

The term you are looking for is *hit detection*.  There are a myriad of ways to achieve it.  Look up *hit detection* in Java for some pointers.

What you have isn't necessarily wrong though.

```
while (true) // I'm not always bad!
```

is used in a lot of applications.  However, while your code isn't completely posted, I don't see anywhere you break from this.  You may be interested in the

```
java.util.Timer
```

and the

```
java.util.TimerTask
```

Both of those have wide application in Java game development

Answer (score 0):

Your sleep time is too low (20 nanoseconds). Increase the time, otherwise it will happen too quick for you to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You are potentially triggering this if condition many many times.

You need some 'rising edge trigger' logic in order to only trigger when the new value goes from false to true, instead of triggering whenever it's true.

```
currentValue = bigLongLogicCheck;
if(!oldvalue&&currentValue) {alert()}
oldvalue = currentValue
```